# PHP sort multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

With my code I can sort all columns individually but I do have an issue with data not being sorted alphabetically / chronologically apart from the 1st column. Please see below what is displayed and then what I need to see.

What is currently displayed (Payment type and Date not sorted):

```
| Account | Payment type |    Date    | Amount |
|:--------|:------------:|:----------:|-------:|
| A001    | Rent         | 2021-06-01 | 150.00 |
| A001    | Deposit      | 2021-04-15 | 200.00 |
| A001    | Rent         | 2021-05-02 | 150.00 |
| A002    | Deposit      | 2021-06-20 | 220.00 |
| A003    | Rent         | 2021-06-02 | 250.00 |
| A003    | Deposit      | 2021-05-25 | 300.00 |
```

What I want to get displayed:

```
| Account | Payment type |    Date    | Amount |
|:--------|:------------:|:----------:|-------:|
| A001    | Deposit      | 2021-04-15 | 200.00 |
| A001    | Rent         | 2021-05-02 | 150.00 |
| A001    | Rent         | 2021-06-01 | 150.00 |
| A002    | Deposit      | 2021-06-20 | 220.00 |
| A003    | Deposit      | 2021-05-25 | 300.00 |
| A003    | Rent         | 2021-06-02 | 250.00 |
```

So in short, I want to sort and display data 1stly by the Account column (which displays correctly) and then by the Date column.

My code currently (and yes I know it's open to sql injection and I am working on that ;-) ):

```
    $orderBy = !empty($_GET["orderby"]) ? $_GET["orderby"] : "contracts_account_nr";
    $order = !empty($_GET["order"]) ? $_GET["order"] : "asc";
    $sql = "SELECT contract.contracts_account_nr, payment.rental_payment_type, payment.rental_payment_amount, payment.rental_payment_date FROM contracts contract RIGHT JOIN rental_payments payment ON contract.contracts_id = payment.contracts_id ORDER BY " . $orderBy . " " . $order;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
    $contractOrder = "asc"; 
    $typeOrder = "asc";  
    $dateOrder = "asc"; 
    if($orderBy == "contract.contracts_account_nr" && $order == "asc") {
    $contractOrder = "desc";    
    }
    if($orderBy == "payment.rental_payment_type" && $order == "asc") {
    $typeOrder = "desc";    
    }
    if($orderBy == "payment.rental_payment_date" && $order == "asc") {
    $dateOrder = "desc";    
    }
```

Your help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The `ORDER BY` clause of a prepared statement can't be bound by placeholders.  That is, the `ORDER BY` clause needs to be fixed.  So, just do that:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ...
ORDER BY Account, Date;
```

If you want to allow your users the possibility of choosing how to sort, then I suggest choosing one or more statements with hard-coded `ORDER BY` clauses, based on the inputs into your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with this code as you have a security issue : [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [SQL injection on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

$order and $orderBy are both retrived with GET method. You should at least protect them with [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: You can also create a PDO object and use `$pdo->prepare()` . By using prepared statements you are protected against SQL injections. The query isn't parsed in the same way as concatenation